# Save on form submit versus save on keypress

Tags: php, database, keypress

I'm using PHP as my scripting language and mySQL as my database.
Im wondering if saving into database on **form submit** is better than saving on every **keypress**.
Which is better in terms of usability/ux and in performance?

Comment: How you would send files on keypress? AJAX?

Comment: yes, my idea is to submit it via ajax

Comment: will the performance go slower when i use keypress?

Comment: If you are doing something more often, then you are doing more work, and performance will go down. It is unlikely to go down in a way anyone will notice on the vast majority of systems (assuming your server can handle the demand).

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this rjmcb?

Comment: I already picked a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving on every keypress means:

1. You'll need a server capable of handling more requests
2. You'll need smarter logic then *every* key press as most people can press keys faster than most connections can round trip an HTTP request. Possibly something like "Every 30 seconds, but only if the data has been changed, but delayed until a response is received for the last request (or it times out)".

Answer (score 1):

Saving on keypress is definitely a very bad idea ! A typical form with 10 fields, will require at least 100 calls to the database. Not very optimal. Even from a UX point of view; But you can create a setTimeout for saving the user input, say, every 30sec (the setTimeout will be initialized after the first field has been changed, for example).